# Subclassed model results in NameError in development environment but not in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my Action model:

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Fold < Action
end

class Check < Action
end

class Call < Action
end

class Bet < Action
end
```

In another model, I have this

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  def Deal.parse_action(action_string)
    case action_string
    when "folds":   Fold.new()
    when "checks":  Check.new()
    when "calls":   Call.new()
    when "bets":    Bet.new()
    when "raises":  Bet.new()
    else nil   
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Now, when I test this if this works in my unit tests, everything appears to work. But as soon as I start the web server in development mode, I get this:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Deal::Fold):
  app/models/deal.rb:115:in `parse_action'
  ...
```

Why does it think Fold exists within the namespace Deal? And why does this not happen in the test environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Rails at work, but I sometimes come across the scenario of a class being known when I'm running tests, but not when I'm running the executable. That happens because I have the requisite "require" statements in my test files for the relevant files, but I hadn't got around to putting the requisite "require" statements in production code.

Comment: This worked for me. I just has to 'require "action.rb"' in the Deal model.

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying that `Fold` exists in the `Deal` namespace, it's saying that it's looking for the constant `Fold` and it's currently inside `Deal`.  For example, try this:

```
class Foo 
  def test; puts Bar; end
end
Foo.new.test
```

and you'll get this:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar
  from (irb):3:in `test'
  from (irb):7
  from :0
```

Rails has stuff to auto-load constants for you and I'm guessing the problem is that you don't have the `Fold` class in its own file. Try putting the `Fold` class definition into it's own file -- `app/models/fold.rb` and see if that helps.  If so, try putting it back in the action.rb file and then doing something that would cause the `Action` file to load before you do the `case` statement, like `x = Action` right before the case statment.  If that works then you need to `require "action.rb"` in `deal.rb` because the issue is that your test code is loading action.rb (possibly through some other test) but your production code isn't.

Comment: You could just require action in deal.rb.

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby to add a method to a class you have declare like so:

```
  class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.parse_action(action_string)
      case action_string
        when "folds":   Fold.new
        ....
```

That may be the source of your problems as well.

Also (sorry to nit pick) but you don't need the parenthesis on `Fold.new`. You are able to pass parameters to methods without using parathesis.

Comment: http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html says There's More Than One Way To Do It.

Comment: BTW, did you mean "without using parentheses"?